# How do I append file, clear form, load file and update listview on button click?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, listview, textbox

I have a directory form which displays the contents of a CSV file in a listview upon load. I am creating a button that sends three user-entered text fields to the CSV file, clears the form textboxes and listview, then loads and displays the updated directory in the listview.

Unfortunately, when the button is clicked, I instead end up with a blank listview, even though the clearForm method comes before loadDirectory and displayDirectory. When I comment out the clearForm function, my listview contains the original list followed by the entire new list, as expected.

```
private void BtnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addRecord(); // Sends text box entries to a file via. streamreader *working*
        clearForm(); // Clears the form *working on standalone clear button*
        loadDirectory(); // Loads CSV file contents to array *working*
        displayDirectory(); // Displays array to listview *working*
    }


public void loadDirectory()
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
        int lineCount = File.ReadLines(path).Count();

        string line;
        int count = -1;
        directoryTable = new record[lineCount];

        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            count++;
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] fields = line.Split(',');

            record currentRecord = new record();
            currentRecord.surname = fields[0];
            currentRecord.forename = fields[1];
            currentRecord.extCode = Convert.ToInt32(fields[2]);
            directoryTable[count] = currentRecord;
        }
        sr.Close();
    }


public void displayDirectory()
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < directoryTable.Length; counter++)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
            lvi.Text = (Convert.ToString(directoryTable[counter].surname));
            lvi.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(directoryTable[counter].forename));
            lvi.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(directoryTable[counter].extCode));
            lvDirectory.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }


public void addRecord()
    {
        string[] newRecord = new string[3];

        newRecord[0] = txtForename.Text;
        newRecord[1] = txtSurname.Text;
        newRecord[2] = txtExtCode.Text;

        // Write newRecord array to last line of directory file
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, append: true);
        sw.WriteLine(newRecord[0] + ", " + newRecord[1] + ", " + newRecord[2]);
        sw.Close();
    }


public void clearForm()
    {
        foreach (Control field in Controls)
        {
            if (field is TextBox)
                ((TextBox)field).Clear();
            else if (field is ListView)
                ((ListView)field).Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you have to remove the blank fields, not only clear them, otherwise the loaded new data maybe are just after many bank fields, this is why you do not see them, the listview appearing blank itself. I am saying that you are probably appending the new data to a list of blanked empty lines in the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the items in the listview and not the listview itself:

```
public void clearForm()
{
    foreach (Control field in Controls)
    {
        if (field is TextBox)
            ((TextBox)field).Clear();
        else if (field is ListView)
            ((ListView)field).Items.Clear();
    }
}
```